# How can you resolve references to db records in other collections before rendering in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using [meteor](http://meteor.com) on a page that displays a list of transactions. Transaction documents look like so:

`{ payer: 'username1', payee: 'username2', amount: 100, date: someDate }`

To display a list of transactions like this:

`<ul class="recent-transactions">
      {{#each transactions}}
        <li>{{this.amount}} to {{this.payee}} from {{this.payer}}</li>
      {{/each}}
   </ul>`

In the helper, or right before rendering the template somehow, I would like to replace the `payee` and `payer` property with the actual user documents I can get with `Meteor.users.findOne({ username: someUsername})` so that the template can look like this:

`<ul class="recent-transactions">
      {{#each transactions}}
        <li>{{this.amount}} to {{this.payee.profile.FirstName}} from {{this.payer.profile.FirstName}}</li>
      {{/each}}
   </ul>`

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could also pretend ```payee``` and ```payer``` are ```_id```s for user records instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a **transform** function (see http://docs.meteor.com/#collections under transform)

```
Template.hello.transactions = function(){
    return Transactions.find({}, {transform: function(doc) {
        var payee = Meteor.users.findOne({username: doc.payee});
        var payer = Meteor.users.findOne({username: doc.payer});
        doc.payer_FirstName = payeer.profile.FirstName;
        doc.payee_FirstName = payee.profile.FirstName;

        return doc;
        }
    });
}
```

The transform function can let you change a document before it is returned, all the existing fields stay and both `payee_FirstName` & `payer_FirstName` are now added as if they were part of the collection.

In the above example I have used `Meteor.users`. Make sure all the user's details are published in a secure fashion. By default I think meteor hides all but the logged in user.

So you can resolve it to a different collection. In this case the `payer`/`payee` record is matched up to the `username` in `Meteor.users`. So you can pull out the payee/payer's details without having to store all of the details in `Transactions`.

Answer (score 0):

I would make transactions into a function that returns the correct data. The point of handlebars is that it is supposed to be 'logic-less' so you should abstract away any processing from the actual template.

I would do it by creating a function for the helper like so:

```
Template.transactionTemplate.transactions = function(){
  recentTransactions = [];
  Transcationscollection.find({/* your query */}).forEach(function(transaction){
    recentTransactions.push({
      "amount"              : transaction.amount,
      "payeeFirstName"      : payee.findOne(/* do something with transaction.payee */).profile.FirstName,
      "payerFirstName"      : payer.findOne(/* do something wtih transaction.payer */).profile.FirstName
    });
  });

  /* Personally I convert it to json to display in handlebars... not sure if you have to its just how I do it. */
  return EJSON.stringify(recentTransactions);
};
```